# Married file jointly, what address i need to use in 1040 form?

Tags: taxes, irs

This is the first time that I file taxes as a married file jointly! I am a resident alien and my wife is non-resident alien. We stayed in two different states. When I fill out the 1040 form and state form, I use my wife's address (NRA) for the home address, not my address, because I will move to another location in a few months?

My question is that OK that we can use the NRA address to file taxes if we choose married file jointly? What is the address used for?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you moving to your wife's address or another (third) location?

Comment: HI, maybe in the future I will move to somewhere.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because you can use your current address and just submit a change of address when you move, or use her address if it will be your permanent address. If you don't know, just use your current address and notify them when it changes.

Comment: I use the NRA address, is that OK? Because I think it is just for receiving the materials mailed from IRS. Any address I think is fine.  We are mailing jointly. My wife will not change her address recently. Is that OK?